# Unexpected json result of org.json & org.json.simple

Tags: java, json, org.json

Issue encounter

1. org.json: null value is missing
2. org.json.simple: Object[] doesn't parse correctly

Expected Result:

> [null,true,123,123.456,"","123asd'\"/\",[null],[true],[123],[123.456],[""],["123asd'\"/\"],[null],[true],[123],[123.456],[""],["123asd'\"/\"],{"0":null},{"0":true},{"0":123},{"0":123.456},{"0":""},{"0":"123asd'\"/\"}]

Actual Result for org.json: null value is missing

> [null,true,123,123.456,"","123asd'\"/\",[null],[true],[123],[123.456],[""],["123asd'\"/\"],[null],[true],[123],[123.456],[""],["123asd'\"/\"],{},{"0":true},{"0":123},{"0":123.456},{"0":""},{"0":"123asd'\"/\"}]

Actual Result for org.json.sample: Object[] is not display correctly

> [null,true,123,123.456,"","123asd'\"/\",**[Ljava.lang.Object;@20ad9418,[Ljava.lang.Object;@31cefde0,[Ljava.lang.Object;@439f5b3d,[Ljava.lang.Object;@1d56ce6a,[Ljava.lang.Object;@5197848c,[Ljava.lang.Object;@17f052a3**,[null],[true],[123],[123.456],[""],["123asd'\"/\"],{"0":null},{"0":true},{"0":123},{"0":123.456},{"0":""},{"0":"123asd'\"/\"}]

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
        map.put(map.size(), null);
        map.put(map.size(), true);
        map.put(map.size(), 123);
        map.put(map.size(), 123.0);
        map.put(map.size(), 123.456);
        map.put(map.size(), "");
        map.put(map.size(), "123asd'\"/\\");
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{null});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{true});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{123});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{123.0});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{123.456});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{""});
        map.put(map.size(), new Object[]{"123asd'\"/\\"});

        List list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add(null);
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add(true);
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add(123);
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add(123.0);
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add(123.456);
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add("");
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        list_temp = new LinkedList();
        list_temp.add("123asd'\"/\\");
        map.put(map.size(), list_temp);

        Map map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), null);
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), true);
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), 123);
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), 123.0);
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), 123.456);
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), "");
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);
        map_temp = new LinkedHashMap();
        map_temp.put(map_temp.size(), "123asd'\"/\\");
        map.put(map.size(), map_temp);

        List list = new LinkedList(map.values());

        //println(new JSONObject(map).toString());
        //println(JSONValue.toJSONString(map));
        println(new JSONArray(list).toString());
        println(JSONValue.toJSONString(list));
    }

    public static <T> void println(T p_t) {
        System.out.println(p_t);
    }

}
```

Comment: Got some code at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two libraries are very feature poor. They do the job for simple cases.

Your test has simply identified that `org.json` doesn't serialize `Map` entries where the value is `null` and `org.json.simple` doesn't have a special case for array types (and therefore defaults to their `toString()` method return value).

Comment: @XYZ That's right. These things are hardcoded in the source and the APIs aren't configurable. Use a more feature rich JSON library.